# Sync files from local filesystem with S3 - one way

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, synchronization, s3cmd

I have a process that generates log files to the local filesystem, and files that are more than 2 weeks old are automatically purged.  I want to use the aws command line tools to sync my folder with S3, with the following behavior:

- No sync of files from S3 to local
- Files are not deleted on S3 when they are purged on the local filesystem.

How does S3 sync work in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [AWS cli](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html):

```
$ aws s3 cp --recursive /path/to/local/files/* s3://bucket/
```

Use a set of IAM credentials that has write-only access to the bucket, so that you can be ensured that no files are ever copied back to the source system.

Comment: This is a solution with extra moving parts. I'd like to achieve this "cp only changed files" (or sync one-way) as well, but without maintaining special IAM policies.

Comment: @Excalibur Cool story, bro. :) If you have another question, then ask it as a question, not as a comment on a ~1.5-year old answer.

Comment: @EEAA: So, I misunderstood the behavior of the "sync" command, partially due to the title of the OP, in that I thought sync was bidirectional. However, I was wrong, and the standard behavior is what I was looking for. Your answer works as well, provided you're not needing the new/updated-files-only functionality of sync. So ultimately, I have nothing meriting a new "question".